# H1 tag border length possible?

Tags: html, css, tags, border

I made myself a full width-image to where i added text.
I've been scratching my head for a great amount of time now. 
I'm trying to find the best solution for adding text with borders both above and below.

However, i would like the borders to be at half the length or less but i simply can't figure it out.

Before the Tag-class i tried using borders on the text-container div but i had problems with centering the text and getting the right alignment.

Here's how it is right now:

CSS:

```
.adcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.adcontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.adcontainertext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}


.advertheading
{
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    line-height: 100px;
    display:inline-block

}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="clear: both;">
<div class="adcontainer"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/LARGE_BANNER-BELOW.jpg?5938182738858039286" />
<div class="adcontainertext">
<h2 class="advertheading" style="font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff;">Join the club</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Best Regards,
Robbin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.adcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.adcontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.adcontainertext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.adcontainertext h2:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 0;
}

.advertheading {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.adcontainertext h2:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="clear: both;">
  <div class="adcontainer">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0786/5107/files/LARGE_BANNER-BELOW.jpg?5938182738858039286" />
    
    <div class="adcontainertext">
      <h2 class="advertheading" style="font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff;">Join the club</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Didn't even know that after and before would work. 
Again, thanks a lot. Much appreciated! Best Regards.

Comment: No problem, an upvote would be much appriciated :)